# Updating Time Only No Date Information

Tags: timer, swiftui, time-format

struct CurrentDateView : View {
    @State var now = Date()

```
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    Text("\(now)")
        .onReceive(timer) {
            self.now = Date()
        }
}
```

}

This code is perfect, but I need the  the Date format removed. I just need the HH:MM:SS showing

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) with Swift 5's string interpolation.

```
struct ContentView: View {  @State var now = Date()

    static let timeFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm:ss a zz"
        return formatter
    }()

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(now, formatter: Self.timeFormat)")
            .onReceive(timer) {_ in
                self.now = Date()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deeply appreciated for you help. Sorry that it took me so long to reply, for I was busy in all kinds of meetings and no way able to get to my computer. THANK YOU AGAIN. Robert